Comedy-thriller that starts with a woman jumping into a young man's car
I think it's between 1995 and 2010. It's a modern movie in the USA, so I'm guessing it's not that old or too close to 1995. All I can remember are some basic mind-capturing moments on how it starts... This is the movie opening:
A young guy is driving through a busy city street (with tall buildings) during the day. As he slows down for a traffic light at a corner, suddenly, out of nowhere, a car comes flying past his front view, spinning in slow motion, from right to left, as he looks at it in awe, not understanding what's going on. He says to himself, "What the ******??" He doesn't even have time to recover when he looks in his rear view mirror (or side mirror) and sees another slow-mo spinning car, rolling towards his car... he is speechless. Before he can get any baring of what's going on, his passenger door opens and a beautiful young girl (in her 20's) jumps into the car, slams the car door shut and shouts "DRIVE!" He says some comedic line like "No! Who are you?" but of course something else happens (as usual in such movies) that makes him step on the accelerator and speed off.
The entire movie star these two people who are the good guys. It's funny and there's lots of action, shooting and car chases. I have been searching for this movie for the past few years now. Any ideas?

Sounds like Final Contract: Death on Delivery from 2006.

David Glover is a young, American man who is working as a courier at his uncle's company, "Berling Express". David is attracted to a female co-worker by the name of Jenny, who also happens to have feelings for him. During one of his courier jobs, the attractive Lara, who claims to be a policewoman, jumps into his car and David finds himself in an exchange of fire. David is willing to help Lara, but soon finds himself framed as the professional assassin LORCA. Now David must run from the police and catch the real LORCA, who is hell-bent on murdering the last surviving witness to a brutal murder.

It's not even on Wikipedia, but you can see the exact scene you're describing (cars flipping by him, him saying "What the...", Lara getting into his car saying "Drive" and him refusing) here:



